# wkhtmltopdf percentage decimals

Tags: html, css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to render a HTML figure to PDF. Each bar is segmented up into several smaller divs which each as a width equal to their value. All of these added together gives 100%. Now each div can have a width in percent with alot of decimals.

The problem is that when this html gets passed through wkhtmltopdf these decimals seems to be ignored. Does anyone know of a way to force wkhtmltopdf to use all decimals when rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this other question has your answer?
[wkhtmltopdf not rendering percentage widths correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333817/wkhtmltopdf-not-rendering-percentage-widths-correctly)

The marked answer points out that wkhtmltopdf does not render decimal pixels, such as 10.5px

A "fix" for the problem was to increase the dpi setting, which did not seem to affect the time it took to generate a PDF.

I have not tested, but I thought this might help.